# Django how to concatenate form data before saving to the database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am building a budgeting web app for many users. The user creates accounts to track different values. The problem is that I cannot make a composite key and need the AccountName to be the primary key.

This poses a challenge. What if users make the same account name? This will happen as some users may make a "Cash" account. My solution to this problem is to name the account in the database the AccountName + the userid. How can I modify the users AccountName in the form to be AccountName + userid?

Desired AccountName examples in the database: Cash1, Cash2

models.py

```
class Account(models.Model):
    DateCreated = models.DateTimeField()
    AccountName = models.CharField(max_length= 100, primary_key=True)
    UserID = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)      
    Type = models.CharField(max_length= 20)
    Balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=8)
    Value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=8)
```

Views.py

```
    @login_required
    def func_AccountsView(request):
        # This filters users accounts so they can only see their own accounts
        user_accounts = Account.objects.filter(UserID_id=request.user).all()

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AddAccount(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                account = form.save(commit=False)
                account.UserID = request.user
                account.AccountName = AccountName + str(request.user) # WHY DOES THIS NOT WORK?
                account.save()
                return redirect('accounts')
            else:
                form = AddAccount()
        else:
            form = AddAccount()


        data = {
            'form':form,
            'data': user_accounts
            }
        return render(request, 'NetWorth/accounts.html', data)
```

forms.py

```
        class AddAccount(forms.ModelForm):
            ''' This is the form that handles additions of an account '''
            class Meta:
                model = Account
                fields = ['AccountName','DateCreated', 'Type', 'Balance', 'Value']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get `AccountName` from form input by getting it from `cleaned_data` then concat with `request.user.pk`. Don't forget to convert `pk` value into `str` otherwise you will getting `TypeError` exception

```
....
account.AccountName = form.cleaned_data.get('AccountName') + str(request.user.pk)
account.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

`request.user` will not work because it is an object which contains other fields.

Also your `AccountName` variable does not represent anything thanks to Eby Sofyan's answer

To fix your problem replace,

```
account.AccountName = form.cleaned_data.get('AccountName') + str(request.user.id)
```